# Error 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable - when appending list inside a for loop

Tags: python, list, pandas

I want to create a new list from a existing list within a for loop and then pass the list through an if else statement, one element at a time. I do not have the proper knowledge to utilize a list in this manner. Hence this post

sample data:

```
f = {'Sales_Person': ['John', 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Rob', 'Mike', 'Miz', 'Sally', 'Buck', 'Roger'],  'location': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NJ', 'PA', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'PA', 'NY', 'NJ'], 'product_code': ['10NYXX', '11NYXX', '10NYXX', '10NJXY', '11PAXY', '11MNYY', '12NJYX', '11PAYY', '12NYXX', '11CAPQ']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = f)
df1['statusNY'] = 'n/a'
df1['statusPA'] = 'n/a'
df1['statusIL'] = 'n/a'
df1['statusOR'] = 'n/a'
df1['statusNJ'] = 'n/a'
```

The data looks like-

[image]

I am taking these column names ['statusNY', 'statusPA', 'statusIL', 'statusOR', 'statusNJ'] and extract state names [NY, PA, IL, OR and NJ] from them. Then I will check if the column 'product_code' contains these state names. If true then assign 1 to 'statusNY', if false assign 0 to 'statusNY'.Similarly for rest of the column names 'statusPA', 'statusIL', 'statusOR', 'statusNJ'

Output should look like:

[image]

I have following code:

```
for col in ['statusNY', 'statusPA', 'statusIL', 'statusOR', 'statusNJ']:
    x = col[6:8]
    df1.loc[df1['product_code'].str.contains(x) == True, col] = '1'
    df1.loc[df1['product_code'].str.contains(x) == False, col] = '0'
```

Ideally the second line should create a list which should be passed through third and fourth line. But this doesn't work.

Then I thought of appending the list -

```
newlist = []
for col in ['statusNY', 'statusPA', 'statusIL', 'statusOR', 'statusNJ']:
    newlist.append[col[6:8]]
```

But ended up getting this error: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable. I googled it and also checked other relevant posts, but the results were not quite relevant to my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `append[col[6:8]]` to `append(col[6:8])`

`append[blah]` is trying to get an element from a function

Comment: I feel such a python noob after realizing this was the error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this, which uses [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html)?

```
def flag_product_code(df, states):
    df = df.copy()

    for state in states:
        df['status' + state] = (df.product_code
                                  .str.contains(state)
                                  .astype(int))

    return(df)

df1.pipe(flag_product_code, ['NY', 'PA', 'IL', 'OR', 'NJ'])
```

This creates a function to flag whichever states you want and appends columns to the original DataFrame.

That said, you will get some unintended results; specifically, row 5 of your data with product_code value '11MNYY' will flag as NY. If you know that product_type will always be formatted like it is in your example data, you might want to check a substring of the product_type.